# How to List Items Per Page Column in C#

Tags: c#, excel, multiple-columns

Using C#, I am trying to list all items per page in following structure:

**Columns**: `Page1 , Page2`

**Values per page**: `Item1, Item2, Item3`

**Expected Output:**

**Sample:**

```
Page1      Page2

Item1      Item1
Item2      Item2
Item3
```

But when I view the Excel file, alignment looks weird. Values are displayed like this:

[image]

Meanwhile, below is the code section where I plot the values for Excel.

```
IXLWorksheet worksheet = newXLWorkbook.Worksheets.Add("Tab 1");

int row = 2;
int col = 1;


foreach (ObjectPage objPage in obj.ObjectPages)
{
    
    worksheet.Cell(1, col).Value = objPage.Name;
    col++;


    foreach (ObjectPage.Section section in objPage.Sections)
    {
                            
        foreach (ObjectPage.SectionField sectionField in section.SectionFields)
        {
            worksheet.Cell(row, col).Value = sectionField.FullName;
            row++;
                                    
            foreach (ObjectField objField in objPage.ObjectFields)
            {
                                        
                //do other process...
      
            }

            row++;
                                    
        }

                                
    }
                            
} 

row = 2;
```

I only included the most important part of the code and not all as it is too long. Hope that I have explained well what I am encountering and hoping anyone can help me on this.

Thanks!

Comment: What Excel library are you using. And why is the code incrementing the `col` variable for each section field? … `worksheet.Cell(row, col++).Value = sectionField.FullName;` … I am guessing this is why the fields are each in a different column. Again, just a guess.

Comment: @JohnG I modified my code and removed the increment for column. But all field values are all under Page 1 column while there are no fields listed under Page 2. How can I list all Page 2 fields under its column? Please note that Page columns are incremented as number of pages per object are not fixed, so it may be 1 or more than 1.

Comment: It is unclear what each `foreach` loop is looping through. In the current code, there are four (4) `foreach` loops? This can easily be done with two (2). I can only guess that `col++` should be inside the second `foreach` loop. In relation to you question “why” are there four (4) `foreach` loops? I would think a simple trace of the code would reveal “where” the `col` and `row` values should be incremented.